# Omit JOINs from View if columns not selected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is a longshot, but is there a way to tell SQL Server to omit doing JOINs if no columns are selected?

The reason I ask is because I have a large nested set of Views (10+ layers deep) with each layer having 5-20 joins in them. I am wondering if there is any way to improve performance other than flattening the joins into this view and removing obsolete ones, as a large number of the joins are completely unused (1:1).

## Example

**Team table**

```
| TeamId | Name     |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | Stack    |
| 2      | Overflow |
```

---

**Score Table**

```
| TeamId | Score |
|--------|-------|
| 1      | 10    |
| 1      | 55    |
| 2      | 1337  |
```

---

**View**

```sql
CREATE VIEW TeamScore
AS
SELECT t.TeamId, t.Name, s.Score
FROM Team t
LEFT JOIN Score s ON t.TeamId = s.TeamId
```

**Sample Query 1**

```sql
SELECT Name FROM TeamScore
```

*Expected Result*

```
| Name     |
|----------|
| Stack    |
| Overflow |
```

I do not want it to join to Score (for performance reasons).

**Sample Query 2**

```sql
SELECT Name, Score FROM TeamScore
```

*Expected Result*

```
| Name     | Score |
|----------|-------|
| Stack    | 10    |
| Stack    | 55    |
| Overflow | 1337  |
```

I do want it to join to `Score` table because it one of its columns is required.

---

I made the relationship in this example 1:n (Team:Score), to demonstrate I am happy to have different number of rows depending if you select score or not, as I know from a business perspective that in my scenario all of the joins in question are 1:1

Ideally some kind of `OPTIONAL LEFT JOIN` operator

Comment: Then what's wrong with the query `SELECT [Name] FROM Team;`? Use the query appropriate to the data you're asking for.

Comment: @MichaelCiechan . . . Then you don't want a view.

Comment: Also, the `JOIN` is required, as there is a one to many relationship. `SELECT [Name] FROM TeamScore` would return **three** rows, not **two**. The problem is you are querying the wrong object.

Comment: I think you should have multiple view for different scenarios, and choose at runtime the one you want to query, depending on the parameters. I haven't seen "optional joins" ever.

Comment: The issue is there are 5 teams owning the joins separately, if I start "duplicating" the join logic into my own Views then there is a bigger maintenance headache as you have to find where that specific join is happening. I guess flattening/duplicating is the only way?

Comment: @Larnu this is a very small hypothetical example, where different teams own different views. I know it would currently return three rows, as it **has** to do the join. But I don't want it to do the join.

Comment: Nested views, also, tend to perform very poorly. SQL isn't like a programming language. Reuse of code (like views) is often detrimental to performance, not beneficial, even if it ends up being a duplicate of code. If you do want to reuse code, you are better off with a **inline** table-value function, but you still should not nest those and should call them individually in the `FROM` to "grow" your dataset. 10 layers of Views is going to , honestly, very likely be awful for performance.

Comment: You can read about the problems of nested views in [The Seven Sins against TSQL Performance](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/), which has the section [Indulging in Nested Views](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven).

Comment: This sounds like an XY issue. Having this level of nested view.. is just a headache on its own. I'd strongly advise to change it. But.. you can technically exclude certain parts of queries by writing a stored procedure which executes the query as dynamic SQL. Allowing you to exclude sections of statements based on parameters. This, however, would require you to have access to the source tables, which seems unlikely considering there's this nested mess of a view. I wouldn't do it however, since that is a whole mess of it's own.